# jinja2 returning wrong values from sqlite database

Tags: html, python-3.x, sqlite, jinja2

I have some code, in Python and sqlite, which when executed and printed, returns the correct data. But when I try pass it to HTML, it is retrieving data from the wrong table and displaying it to the HTML. 
For example, I execute the following python code:

```
comments = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM comments''')
conn.commit    
for each in comments:
    print(each)
newsubs = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE Signiture = signiture AND Client_ID = client_ID ORDER BY date DESC''')
conn.commit()
print("hello")
var = "hello,!"
return render_template('profile.html', comments = comments, newsubs = newsubs)
```

Then, I have the following HTML code calling in comments and newsubs to display the data:

```
{% for y in newsubs %}
            <br>
                <div id="subcss">
            <legend><strong> {{ y[2] }} </strong> {{ y[4] }} <br><br></legend>
                {{ y[3] }} <br><br>
                <p id = "sig"><strong>Signiture:</strong> {{ y[5] }}</p>
                {{ y[1] }} <br><br>
            <div id="subcss">
            <form action="/comments" method="post">
                <textarea name="comment" rows="7" cols="76">Write a comment...</textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br><br>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">View Comments</button>
            <div id="comdiv">
                {% for z in comments %}
                    <strong>Date:</strong> {{ z[0] }} <br>
                    <strong>Comment:</strong> {{ z[1] }} <br><br>
                    {{ z[2] }}
                    <br>{ z[3] }} {{ z[4] }}
                <br>
                {% endfor %}
            </form><br>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is is that the output to the webpage from this code:

```
{% for z in comments %}
                    <strong>Date:</strong> {{ z[0] }} <br>
                    <strong>Comment:</strong> {{ z[1] }} <br><br>
                    {{ z[2] }}
                    <br>{ z[3] }} {{ z[4] }}
                <br>
                {% endfor %}
```

Is displaying data from the submissions table, not the comments table. 
Any help or anything is greatly appreciated.